# smarty как перечислить несколько условий в if

Tags: php, smarty

требуется по условию выводить код на определенных страницах.
как такой кусок в или оформить грамотно на Smarty ?

```
{if (($page.url != '/')||
    ($page.url != '/about-us')||
    ($page.url != '/news')||
    ($page.url != '/otzyvy')||
    ($page.url != '/contacts')||
    ($page.url != '/mail')||
    ($page.url != '/privacy-policy'))
}                 
    <div class="inner_block">
          <ul class="adw-block">
            <li><p>first</p></li>
            <li><p>second</p></li>
            <li><p>third</p></li>
            <li><p>fourth</p></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Каких-либо специальных кратких вариантов подобной записи нет. Просто вычислите сначала значение условия, потом используйте

```
{$showAds = !in_array($page.url, ['/', '/about-us', '/news'])}
{if $showAds}           
    <div class="inner_block">
          <ul class="adw-block">
            <li><p>first</p></li>
            <li><p>second</p></li>
            <li><p>third</p></li>
            <li><p>fourth</p></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
{/if}
```